# how many bits to write $\sqrt x $?

Tags: asymptotics, logarithms

x is an integer, and i can write it with $\log_2 x$ bit, and, viceversa, with $n$ bit i can write a number till $2^n$..
but..
how many bits to write $\sqrt x$ ?

EDIT: the integer part!

Comment: if sqrt{x} is irrational I don't really understand what this statement means.

Comment: @Qiaochu the floor of $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: @nkint Suppose $x$ is an $n$-bit number. How big can $\sqrt{x}$ be? How many bits do you need to store all possible values of $\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: @Yuval: "how big can $\sqrt x$ be" is the point :-) sure more less that $\frac{x}{2}$.. i can't see a link with exponential.. the problem is that i don't manage to solve $log^{\frac{1}{2}}x$.

Comment: @nkint:  you need $\log (x^{\frac{1}{2}})$, not $log^{\frac{1}{2}}x$.  That should help

Comment: mhmmm one moment.. no! $\sqrt x$ is long..$\sqrt x$!  so the formula is $log_2 \sqrt x$ = $\frac{log x}{2}$

Comment: ohu yeah ross, i've got the point and i was writing last comment while you get me the solutions! thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sqrt{x}$ is not an integer, it will take a **lot** of bits.

Hint:  If it is an integer (or you are just writing the integer part) you should have a rule of logarithms that will help.  Do you know another way to express $\sqrt{x}$?

Answer (score 2):

$log_2 \sqrt n = log_2 n^{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{2} log_2 x$

thanks to Yuval Filmus and Ross Millikan for comments